# Why list copy() adds an extra dimension to an array that contains itself in python?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, list-comprehension

I was experimenting with lists inside lists and I found this property very curious and can't really wrap my head around why this happens:

So, python has this notation for when it identifies that a list contains itself when printed: `[[...]]`

And I created this simple program to print that line:

```py
arr = []
arr.append(arr)
print(arr)
```

*Output:*

```
[[...]]
```

Then I went further and appended the list twice, and to no surprises, I got an array with two elements that contained themselves:

```py
arr = []
arr.append(arr)
print(arr)
print('********')
arr.append(arr)
print(arr)
```

*Output:*

```
[[...]]
********
[[...], [...]]
```

After that, I decided to see how a shallow copy of these infinite arrays would look like and I got really surprised and can't explain the phenomena:

```py
arr = []
arr.append(arr)
print(arr)
print(arr.copy())
print('********')
arr.append(arr)
print(arr)
print(arr.copy())
```

*Output*

```
[[...]]
[[[...]]]
********
[[...], [...]]
[[[...], [...]], [[...], [...]]]
```

What is going on here?? This creates an extra dimension??

To me, geometrically, this seems like the copy() created the same structure as the original array, and then where it was supposed to put references of the elements, it actually put the reference of the whole original object!

I mean,

For the first element, let's suppose that the object `[[...]]`  has reference 0x11AA, so, copy creates its structure as a copy of the original structure (Asterisk as a visible placeholder for an object reference, for example purposes): `[*]`(One list with one element) and then, it gives the asterisk the reference of the object `[[...]]` , resulting in `[[[...]]]`.

For the second, the copied structure looks like: `[*, *]` (One list with two elements) and then, the reference of the whole object `[[...], [...]]` is given to each element (asterisk).

Why is this like so???

I am really confused and can't understand why this has such behavior

Comment: The copied list is distinct from the original; there's now one more level of lists before you reach the recursion.  In other words, you've changed from `a -> a -> ...` to `c -> a -> a -> ...`.  Since the outer list is no longer part of the recursion, its square brackets get printed out as normal.

Comment: "where it was supposed to put references of the elements, it actually put the reference of the whole original object" - each element of the original list **is** "the whole original object", because you appended the original list to itself.

Comment: @jasonharper okay, this is very clear to me now!! Cheers for the simple yet effective example!